# Hibernate Envers - how to search non audited entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I store to database entity ***LOG*** which is immutable (doesn't change) but other classes (entities) which it includes can change do I have to annotate this one with *@Audited* (I mean log)? This creates extra table of history which doesn't make any sense because ***LOG*** can not change so it is just creating duplicates. But when I don't add @Audited I can not search for it using AuditReader (AuditQuery) ... Could anyone help me here?

EXAMPLE:

```
LOG[id, weather_station_id, measurement ...]
WEATHER_STATION[id, name ...]
SENSOR[id, name, weather_station_id ...]
```

The name of sensor or weather station can change and I need to be able to get the original data when the LOG was created.

***EDITED:***
I will try to describe my problem in more details. I am getting some measurements from sensors of weather station which has some sensors. I need to store these measurements into database to be able to read them later (I am calling this "log"). The measurement value can not change. The log class (entity) has reference (relation ship) with weatherStation class which has reference to multiple sensors. Some informations about weatherStation and sensors can change during time such as firmware version etc. And I need to be able to get the whole log class from database at the time of measurement to be able to check the firmware number when the measurement was made for example.

I would like to achieve something like *Log getLogFromDb(Long id)* which would return the log class including weatherStation information at the time of measurement and information about sensors at the time of measurement.

I was able to get similar behavior with Hibernate Envers when I marked WeatherStation, Sensor and **LOG** as audited. But as you can see the LOG table doesn't change at all so it make no sense to have log history table because it just includes always the same data.

I hope my problem is clearer now.

***This is how I do it right now:***

```
public Optional<Log> findVersionById(Integer id) {
    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
    AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Log.class, true, false);
    query.add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.ADD));
    query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id));
    Log log = (Log)query.getSingleResult();

    return Optional.of(log);
}
```

Comment: Please share the Log entity mapping along with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HQL for searching both, audited and normal entities. Try debugging to see how the metamodel types for audited entities are structured. You can access the metamodels by looking into `EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities()`

Comment: Hi, could you give me some hint, I am not sure how exactly you mean I should use it. I need to achieve same behavior as with audited entity just not to create the table.

Comment: I suggest you simply don't use `AuditReader` but instead use HQL for querying audited entities. Not sure if you even have audited entities, but to me, it seems like you don't. Please share more details like the entity model or queries you want to do, if you still have questions.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec, I will edit original post.

Comment: It is done even with the way how I am able to achieve it right now.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "at the time of the measurement". As far as I understand, this has nothing to do with Hibernate Envers. Just use HQL to join the data based on the foreign keys.

Comment: I guess you are right, it is possible to do it manually but as you can see, I am able to write it without specifying query on my own. With "at time of the measurement" I mean I need to get the information about weather station and sensor how they were at the time when the measurement was made (stored to database). I have never worked with HQL and Hibernate Envers tables could you give me example how to get for example some entity at specific time using HQL (or send me some link) thank you.

Comment: Just look into the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql and specifically into joins: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join